# How to perform a forEach loop on a variable defied as string | Array<string>?

Tags: javascript, typescript, airbnb-js-styleguide

I am using the airbnb typescript style guideline and I have defined a type like this:

```
export interface Question {
  id: number;
  type: 'text' | 'multipleOption' | 'checkBox';
  question: string;
  answer: string | Array<string>;
}
```

A variable that fits this interface is created and I need to perform a forEach on the answer to check some conditions, but I get a linting error saying that

```
Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'.
  Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string'
```

I would like to perform a check that enables me to perform this foreach without modifying the guideline configuration or changing the type in the interface Question definition.

I have tried:

```
if (question.answer.constructor === Array) {
    question.answer.forEach(...)
}

if (Array.isArray(question.answer)) {
    question.answer.forEach(...)
}
if (typeof question.answer !== 'string') {
    question.answer.forEach(...)
}
```

But none of the above removes the lining error.

Comment: `const answers = <Array<string>>question.answer; answers.forEach(...)` - let me know if that works and I'll post it as an answer. cheers

Comment: The latter two look good.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgRQFdgBnGBCJOAbwCg5EATALjiUIFsAjNAbnrgwAnmGCsA5KhAxxcAD5xxHQgBtyYFcADyYcpVkLx2ABbBsAawBCEEOP4MAjsTIUkrMlGQBze3ExISAHc0dxhPJC95OABBKChMIQAeD28APn4AX1psSjI4J1I9KgBeGgy-EgJnIv5aBHQ4AAoCl0oAOn8gtDacgLDCbBhoOGLRmLiEgEoaAUdq1w6A4Kg29GgAURxjRt6SCE02lQgvSdos+qbY+KE2hBIrhOb59s7lyem6BjnChdfutagmxMO1y+2Ah2Op3ODUawlEEAaLSKiy6UDgAEIxuIUhFxB9ZvlnkgUctVhstiCAmCISczkA), all three approaches work fine.

Comment: I don't know much about the airbnb guide, but that interface is ill-designed. You might be better off with a tagged union of three question interfaces with respective `answer` types.

Comment: Are you sure this is a linter warning? It sounds like a typescript error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (Array.isArray(question.answer)) {
    (question.answer as Array<string>).forEach(...)
}
```

also you can do this to have a uniform code

```js
    let answers : Array<string> = [];
    if (Array.isArray(question.answer)) {
        answers = [...question.answer];
    } else if (!!question.answer){
        answers = [question.answer];
    }

    answers.forEach(answer => ....)
```

Comment: This cast is not necessary. `Array.isArray` already acts as a type guard.

Comment: Btw, no reason for cloning the array. Just write `const answers = Array.isArray(question.answer) ? question.answer : [question.answer];`